# Highlight the particular text from it's index value

Tags: angular, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I tried to implement text-to-speech search on my website.
What I tried to do this is to just highlight the text that what it speaking.
Here is my code

```
this.utterThis.onboundary=function(event){
    if(event.name=='word'){
      this.progress_index=event.charIndex;
      console.log(textcontent.charAt(this.progress_index))
    }
```

In console log, what it `returns` is the **index value of the first word**. 
It tells that all the `p` tag text is in `textcontent` variable.

```
var textcontent = (<HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById("description")).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

So what I actually want is to **highlight** the text that it spoken using the index value.
**Note:** event.name returns `word`.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it

```
this.utterThis.onboundary = function (event) {
    if (event.name == 'word') {
      this.progress_index = event.charIndex;

      this.remainingword = this.utterThis.text.substring(this.progress_index, this.utterThis.text.indexOf(" "));

      var html:string = this.utterThis.text.substring(this.progress_index, this.utterThis.text.indexOf(" ")).fontcolor("blue") + this.utterThis.text.substring(this.remainingword.length + 4);
      console.log(html);
      (<HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById("description")).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
    }
  }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that way

```js
var event = {
  name: 'highlightText',
  charIndex: 18
};
var text = 'lorem ipsum dolar highlightText sit amet';

var html = text.substring(0, event.charIndex)
            + '<span class="highlight">' + event.name + '</span>'
            + text.substring(event.charIndex + event.name.length, text.length);
            
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```